# perl extract text between html tags using regex

Tags: html, regex, perl, tags

I'm new to Perl and im trying to extract the text between all `<li> </li>` tags in a string and assign them into an array using regex or split/join.

e.g.

```
my $string = "<ul>
                  <li>hello</li>
                  <li>there</li>
                  <li>everyone</li>
              </ul>";
```

So that this code...

```
foreach $value(@array){
    print "$value\n";
}
```

...results in this output:

```
hello
there
everyone
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to use regex for HTML.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454)

Comment: Yes, regex is a horribly wrong tool for this.

Comment: regex is not a horrible tool, if it fits you're need then use it, probably faster then HTML parser. With HTML parser you know its valid HTML and you can walk through the tree.

Comment: Yes, I think you are being too harsh on the OP. S/he is not asking for a complex html parser, but something reasonable. Just need to split the string on `\n` and search for something like either `<li>(.+?)</li>` or `<li>([^<])`. I would answer but I have tried too hard to forget PERL.

Answer (score 7):

**Note:** Do not use regular expressions to parse HTML.

This first option is done using [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder), one of many HTML Parsers that is available to use. You can visit the link provided above and read the documentation and see the example's that are given.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $str 
   = "<ul>"
   . "<li>hello</li>"
   . "<li>there</li>"
   . "<li>everyone</li>"
   . "</ul>"
   ;

# Now create a new tree to parse the HTML from String $str
my $tr = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($str);

# And now find all <li> tags and create an array with the values.
my @lists = 
      map { $_->content_list } 
      $tr->find_by_tag_name('li');

# And loop through the array returning our values.
foreach my $val (@lists) {
   print $val, "\n";
}
```

If you decide you want to use a regular expression here (I don't recommend). You could do something like..

```
my $str
   = "<ul>"
   . "<li>hello</li>"
   . "<li>there</li>"
   . "<li>everyone</li>"
   . "</ul>"
   ;

my @matches;
while ($str =~/(?<=<li>)(.*?)(?=<\/li>)/g) {
  push @matches, $1;
}

foreach my $m (@matches) {
   print $m, "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
hello
there
everyone
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** [Do not use regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/1733163).

[hwnd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2206004/hwnd) has already provided one HTML Parser solution.

However, for a more modern HTML Parser based off css selectors, you can check out [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM).  There is a very informative 8 minute intro video at `Mojocast episode 5`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::DOM;

my $html = do {local $/; <DATA>};

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($html);

for my $li ($dom->find('li')->text->each) {
    print "$li\n";
}

__DATA__
<ul>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>there</li>
  <li>everyone</li>
</ul>
```

Outputs:

```
hello
there
everyone
```